# Scraping text from specific HTML elements, from URL list, combined with Regex, and then concatenating them in a .csv

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, xpath, python-requests

I need to scrape all `li` elements containing the word GAP, regardless of case and signs - I need to catch *'Gap' 'gap-' '-gap' 'GAP'*, etc. I need the whole text inside of those `li` elements and they have some extra tags inside, which proved to be problematic.

Here is an instance of one of the elements I need to scrape, inside one of the pages:

```py
<li>
  The GAP Group, 
  <span class="MathTeX">$GAP$</span>
  <script type="math/tex">GAP</script> 
  " groups, algorithms, and programming, version 4.4.12 (2008), http://www.gap-system.org. "
</li>
```

Here is how the text looks on the page - and this is the full text I need to scrape, but only parts of it come out because of the extra tags inside the `li` element:

"The GAP Group, $GAP$ groups, algorithms, and programming, version 4.4.12 (2008), http://www.gap-system.org."

Here is what I tried:

```py
url_lst = ['some URLs']

for page3 in url_lst:
    page3 = requests.get(page3)
    tree3 = html.fromstring(page3.content)
    targets3 = tree3.xpath('//li[contains(text(), "gap")]')
    for target in targets3:
        print(target.text)
```

Here is the result displayed:

```py
  The GAP Group, GAP – groups, algorithms and programming, version 4.10, Available from http://www.gap-system.org, 2018. 



  The GAP Group, (2008). (http://www.gap-system.org). 

  The GAP Group, 2019. GAP – Groups, Algorithms, and Programming, Version 4.10.1; https://www.gap-system.org.
```

It catches only some of them, only those containing exactly the same word I put 'gap' and it partially catches those which have extra tags inside the li element - it only catches the part until it reaches the first extra tag inside - as I show in the top.

I know I need to add Regex in order to ignore case but I don't know how - this is the first problem. And the bigger problem is to catch the whole text in the `li` element including the text in the extra tags. And finally I need to concatenate all results in a .csv file which I can then load in pandas and continue analysing. I do not mind if the solution uses lxml, xpath or selenium + bs4 as long as it works fine. Thank you for the help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text() filter wil only filter on the first text()-node. That is your example everything before `<span class="MathTeX">$GAP$</span>`.

To filter on all content use the `.`

And since XPath 1.0 does not have any regexp functions, you could use this:

```
targets3 = tree3.xpath('//li[contains(., "gap") or contains(.,"GAP")]')
```